# How to write wave equation in a reference frame?

Tags: waves, reference-frames

A plane sound wave is travelling in a medium. In reference to a **frame A**, its equation is 
$$y=A \cos (\omega t - k x)$$
In reference to a **frame B**, moving with a constant velocity $\vec{v}$ in the direction of propagation of the wave, the equation of the wave will be:
$$y=A \cos \bigl[(\omega-k\cdot v) t-k x\bigr]$$

but I am getting $y=A \cos [(\omega+k\cdot v) t-k x]$!

I solved it as follows: The equation connecting the two reference frames has coordinates related as $x'=x-vt$. Substituting this in the given equation yields
$$y=A \cos [(\omega+k\cdot v) t-k x]$$

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wave equation in the reference frame **B** has to be expressed in terms of $x'$, not $x$. Thus you would have:
$$y=A\cos(\omega t-kx)=A\cos\big[\omega t-k(x'+vt)\big]=A\cos\big[(w-kv)t-kx'\big].$$

I think that's the mistake you're looking for.

Comment: thank you very much i got clarity where i made my mistake:)

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the wave when the observer is at rest is $\dfrac \omega k$.

If the observer is moving at a velocity $v$ in the direction of wave propagation then the wave speed as measured by the moving observer is $\dfrac \omega k-v = \dfrac{\omega-kv}{k}=\dfrac {\omega'}{k}$.

So for the moving observer $y=a\cos(\omega' t−kx) = a\cos((\omega - kv) t−kx)$.

This is just a variation of the Doppler effect formula that you have probably derived in the past for the frequency measured by an observe, $\omega'$,  moving away at speed, $v$, from a source of frequency $\omega$, $\omega' = \omega\left (1-\dfrac{v}{v_{\rm phase}}\right )=  \omega\left (1-\dfrac{v}{\omega/k}\right )=\omega - kv,$ where the phase velocity of the wave is $\dfrac \omega k$.